# Optimal number of folds for nested cross-validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, rule-of-thumb

I'm doing nested cross-validation on a classification problem (inner loop to tune hyperparameters, outer loop to select algorithm).

I've often heard that a reasonable number of folds for standard (I.e.: not nested) cross-validation is 5 or 10.

Is there a similar rule of thumb for nested cross-validation?
Should I have more folds in the inner or the outer? How many?

I'm not looking for a definitive answer, I'm just curious to hear what people usually go for.

Comment: which classifiers are in the outer, and what hyperparameters are in the inner? Also, what is the data and the problem being solved